# Material TextView's placholder not working

Tags: ios, swift, textview, cosmicmind

my material textview's placeholder is neither working from interface builder nor from code.

```
import Material

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: TextView!
```

I have tried in viewdidload

```
descriptionTextView.placeholderNormalColor = Color.black
descriptionTextView.placeholderLabel.text = "sdsd"
```

getting error in console if tring from code

> Failed to set (placeholder) user defined inspected property on
>   (UITextView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug which was fixed recently. See: https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/commit/7d45b9431b78d0367eddcbd2eb9b4ad65b3ce458.

To download the latest pod version you need to specify this in your Podfile:

```
pod 'Material', :git => 'https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material.git'
```

Then, you can change your code to:

```
textView.placeholderColor = Color.black
textView.placeholder = "sdsd"
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: do you also know how to update only the material cocoapods in my pod file.., i do not want to update all other pods..

Comment: I have not tried the answer yet.., but don't worry i'll accept it once i get the solution from this answer

Comment: pod update Material worked for updating only material framework.., thanks @Pranav

Comment: Happy to help! Is the placeholder text working as well?

Comment: yes it works very well., not checked about animated placeholder same as of uitextfield

Comment: to set color of `TextField`, try setting `placeholderNormalColor` and `placeholderActiveColor`. The placeholder text can be set in the same way as `TextView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155275/discussion-between-er-khatri-and-pranav-kasetti).